# One vertex, how many triangles ok for game?

Tags: vertex-paint

What the best practice on how many triangles can you create with one vertex when exporting for a game? is there a limit?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115226/low-poly-modern-2018-standards