# Blender General Best Practices (to affect a game's performance as little as possible)

Tags: unity, performance

I've started modeling a few weeks ago by doing some anvils/random objects/humanoids and animations. It seems that for some of them I used too many unnecessary vertices (and perhaps modifiers) after instantiating loads of them on my Unity project.

I was reading this [page](https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/basic-optimise-models-for-export-to-games.php) where they share some basic tips to reduce a model's rendering cost but maybe you guys have some other useful links that you could share and/or general tips. For example, I know that we should start with a model with as few vertices as possible and from there model it and apply modifiers on top of it, but how "costly" are these modifiers?

Sorry if this question has been posted already but I couldn't find an answer that address my current problems. If there is, please leave it in here, if you don't mind!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any clear definition of game-ready models?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100876/is-there-any-clear-definition-of-game-ready-models)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115226/low-poly-modern-2018-standards/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Obrigado, Duarte. Much appreciated